# Issues with links in Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bit of a noob to front end, so bear with me. I tried searching a bit and couldn't get a great answer on this:

I have a site in staging right now at http://mishquastaging.location8.net.

There are social media icons to the left of the search bar. The links work just fine in Chrome but aren't playing nice in Safari. I don't see any errors on the page via Safari's development tools, so I was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue before. I'm sure it's something that I'm not looking for.

Safari 6.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.8.4

```
    <div class="container head">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12 clearfix">
                <div class="top row">

                                                    <div class="span8 logo image">
                                <a href="http://mishquastaging.location8.net/" title="Mishqua" rel="home">
                                    <img src="http://mishquastaging.location8.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/websitelogo.png" alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                    <div class="searchcart span4">


                                                    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://mishquastaging.location8.net/" class="topsearch form-horizontal">
                                <div>
<!-- ADDITION BY PETE - Social Icons Moved here out of footer! -->
                        <ul class="social-icons">

                    <!-- Social Networks -->
                    <li><a href="http://facebook.com/mishquahandbags" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/mishquabagsrhot" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>                                                                              <li><a href="http://instagram.com/mishqua" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

                                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" class="top-search" />
                                    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                                </div>
                            </form>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help!
-Pete

Comment: Please add code to your question to create a repro, so that the question remains useful to future visitors even after you've fixed the linked site.

Comment: What @Jeroen said. And also add where you are testing and and what Safari version is. Windows Safari 5? Mac OSX Safari 6? iOS 4.3 Mobile Safari? etc

Comment: Woh, tried to add the html involved... this is using Wordpress with a customized theme though... providing the CSS would be rough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I couldn't really provide all off the CSS for you because it'd be a lot of code. But the thing that was causing my issues was that the icons were using

```
{display: inline}
```

instead of

```
{display: inline-block}
```

That fixed it right up.

Answer (score 0):

Have seen the issue before. It is probably due to your z-index's though I can't be sure without code. All you need to do is set the z-index of all the other elements on the bar to 0 and those items to something higher than 1